# iphone Launch image app

Tags: xcode

I added an image as a launch image iphone app in xcode using the property box.

Now I want to erase that image but I can't. The image is still appearing despite I erase the image from xcode and from the project folder. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> should do a thorough clean and remove any lingering references to that image provided that you have actually removed it properly otherwise.

@Aalok's comment seems to indicate they don't understand which keys to press. Does it help if I use the symbols?

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: +1 for this fine answer; also, do the clean command-key combination from within Xcode and if that doesn't work, delete the previously built app from your simulator or device.

Comment: Hi how you put this buttons ?? :) will you please tell me about it or any link to read :)

Comment: Just press the buttons all at once. I've edited my answer to use the symbols too